# On the set $\mathbb{R}^2$, define $(x,y) R (a,b)$ if and only if $x^2-y =a^2-b$. Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: equivalence-relations

On the set  $\mathbb{R}^2$, define $(x,y) R (a,b)$ if and only if $x^2-y =a^2-b$. Show that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

---

**1)** $\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}$ 
, we have $(x,y) R (x,y)$ since $x^2-y = x^2-y$, which shows
that $R$ is **reflexive**

**2)**  If $(x,y) R (a, b)$, then $x^2-y=a^2-b$ , and so $a^2-b=x^2-y$ , which implies
that $(a,b)R(x,y)$, and so $R$ is **symmetric**

**3)** If $(x,y)R(a,b)$ and $(a,b)R(c,d)$ , then $x^2-y=a^2-b$ and $a^2-b=c^2-d$
The transitive law for equality implies that $x^2-y=c^2-d$, and
therefore $(x,y)R(c,d)$, so $R$ is **transitive.**

We conclude that **$R$** is an equivalence
relation.

Is correct  my proof?

Comment: Yes, except for a typo in 2): "$(a,b)R(c,d)$" should be "$(a,b)R(x,y)$".

Comment: at 2) you wrote at the end $(a,b)R(c,d)$ and not $(a,b)R(x,y)$ and at 3) you said that The transitive law for equality implies that $x^2-y=a^2-b$ instead of $x^2-y=c^2-d$

Comment: In general, any function $f:A \to B$ induces an equivalence relation on $A$ where $a_1 \sim a_2 \iff f(a_1)=f(a_2) \in B$. Yours is just the case where $A=\mathbb{R}^2$, $B=\mathbb{R}$, and $f(a_1,a_2)=a_1^2-a_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct; good job! This indeed mostly boils down to utilizing the fact that equality itself is an equivalence relation.

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing of substance to add.*

Comment: Better late than never for an answer, indeed.